# How to Split text by Numbers and Group of words

Tags: java, regex

Assuming I have a string containing 
 - some comma separated string
 - and text

```
  my_string =  "2 Marine Cargo       14,642 10,528       16,016 more text 8,609 argA 2,106 argB"
```

I would like to extract them into an array that is split by "Numbers" and "group of words"

```
 resultArray = {"2", "Marine Cargo", "14,642", "10,528", "16,016",
                "more text", "8,609", "argA", "2,106", "argB"};
```

note 0: there might be multiple spaces between each entries, which should be ignored.

note 1: "Marine Cargo" and "more text" is not separated into different strings since they are a group of words without numbers separating them.
while argA and argB are separated because there's a number between them.

Comment: `2 Marine Cargo`, how do we know that `Cargo` belongs to `Marine`?

Comment: is the value "14,642" as single value or two values e.g: "14" and "642" in your expected output?

Comment: Not enough information to solve this problem really. How do we know that `Marine Cargo` should be a single element? Shouldn't it be joined with the `2` resulting in `2 Marine Cargo`? Then we could assume each element has length of 20-25 characters with some padding added.

Comment: @StephanHogenboom ya 14,642 is the single value

Comment: do you want to split your line by "Numbers" and "group of words"?

Comment: @AngelKoh by group of words

Comment: I have rephrased your question and title. your previous title was too generic, and question too ambiguous (resulting in a wave of downvotes.) hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try splitting using this regex

```
([\d,]+|[a-zA-Z]+ *[a-zA-Z]*) //note the spacing between + and *.
```

- [0-9,]+  // will search for one or more digits and commas
- [a-zA-Z]+ *[a-zA-Z]* // will search for a word, followed by a space(if any) followed by another word(if any).

  ```
  String regEx = "[0-9,]+|[a-zA-Z]+ *[a-zA-Z]*";
  ```

you use them like this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  String input = new String("2 Marine Cargo       14,642 10,528       16,016 more text 8,609 argA 2,106 argB");
  System.out.println("Return Value :" );      

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9,]+|[a-zA-Z]+ *[a-zA-Z]*");

  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
  while (m.find()) { 
         System.out.println(">"+m.group(0)+"<");  
         result.add(m.group(0));

   }
}
```

The following is the output as well as a detailed explaination of the RegEx that is autogenerated from https://regex101.com

[image]

```
1st Alternative [0-9,]+
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9,]+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)


2nd Alternative [a-zA-Z]+ *[a-zA-Z]*
Match a single character present in the list below [a-zA-Z]+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
 * matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character present in the list below [a-zA-Z]*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
```

Answer (score 1):

If spaces are your problem. String#split takes a regex as parameter. Then you could do this:
`my_list = Arrays.asList(my_string.split("\s?"));`

But, this won't solve all the problems, like those mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like so:

```
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    String prev = null;
    for (String w: my_string.split("\\s+")) {
        if (w.matches("\\d+(?:,\\d+)?")) {
            if (prev != null) {
                strings.add(prev);
                prev = null;
            }
            strings.add(w);
        } else if (prev == null) {
            prev = w;
        } else {
            prev += " " + w;
        }
    }
    if (prev != null) {
        strings.add(prev);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [Angel Koh solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593978/7240806) and want to add on it. His solution will only match if the numeric part consists out of one or two parts.

If you also want to capture parts consisting out of three or more parts you have to alter the regex a bit to: `([\d,]+|[a-zA-Z]+(?: *[a-zA-Z])*)`
The non capturing group `(?: *[a-zA-Z])`  repeats infinite times, if needed and will capture all pure numeric parts.